# Get a place from the Places here-api using the id

Tags: here-api

Although there is a place lookup from the ID of other Here Services (https://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/places/topics_api/resource-lookup.html)...   I can't find a way to lookup place details using the actual placeID...   I'd like to be able to cache the id and give my user recent places they've viewed.

Is this possible...  in the detailed response or the searches all provide the ID...  but is it useable as I describe?

Sample output from Autocomplete for the Atlanta Airport is below:

```
   {
      "title": "ATL",
      "highlightedTitle": "<b>ATL</b>",
      "vicinity": "6000 N Terminal Pkwy<br/>College Park, GA 30320",
      "highlightedVicinity": "6000 N Terminal Pkwy<br/>College Park, GA 30320",
      "position": [
        33.640397,
        -84.450922
      ],
      "category": "airport",
      "href": "https://places.api.here.com/places/v1/places/840djgzq-aea3f677bbd744ab855203f2ba20281b;context=Zmxvdy1pZD05MmE2ZDVkNS05MDZiLTU3YTQtOGM3NC00MTMxYjY5YzllNDlfMTQ5NzE0NTc4ODAwNl83OTUzXzcwMjEmcmFuaz0w?app_id=eo36dAgbCSxzcLGxzyjZ&app_code=jDJSp_MrBeF6jbuZXUSQqw",
      "type": "urn:nlp-types:place",
      "resultType": "place",
      "id": "840djgzq-aea3f677bbd744ab855203f2ba20281b"
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

To get details of particular place you need to use URL from `href` attribute. If you want, then you can create a map with key as a value of `id` attribute and value as URL from `href` attribute.

Comment: Thanks.   I am not sure how 'static' the href is...   seems the docs indicate the flow should be to retrieve it on demand.